# Applying auto.arima() across list elements to forecast

Tags: r

I'm trying to do the following, but am getting hung up on the final list-wise application of a function (#4 below -- *#1-3 are just the setup for the question*):

1. Split a time-series dataframe into a list by segment
2. Split each of those into a training and testing set
3. Build arima models for each segment, (forecasting revenue, with orders as an *xreg*), using auto.arima() (on the training set)
4. Use each segment's arima model to forecast revenue, using the order values from the next period

(1): Data:

```
library(plyr); library(xts); library(forecast)
set.seed(1234)

data <- data.frame(
    date = seq(as.Date('2014-05-01'), length = 31, by = '1 day'),
    segment = c(rep('High', 31), rep('Med', 31), rep('Low', 31)),
    orders = sample(50:100, 93, replace=TRUE),
    revenue = sample(1500:3000, 93, replace=TRUE))
```

Set the training and test periods:

```
train_dates <- as.Date('2014-05-01') + 0:19
test_dates <- as.Date('2014-05-21') + 0:10
```

(2):  Split the dataframe into a list, by "segment," and make each element of the list an XTS object so we can use it in forecasting:

```
xtsFunc <- function(x) {
    as.xts(x[,3:4], order.by=x$date)
}

# Training and test lists:
train_list <- dlply(subset(data, date %in% train_dates), .(segment), xtsFunc)
test_list <- dlply(subset(data, date %in% test_dates), .(segment), xtsFunc)
```

(3): Now, I want to use auto.arima() on the "train_list" object. That's easy enough:

```
arimaFunc <- function(x){
    auto.arima(x[,'revenue'], xreg=x[,'orders'])
}

train_arimas <- llply(train_list, arimaFunc)
```

(4): But now we run into the problem, Part 4 in the list up top. I want to take the arima models I've just created for each segment's training dates and use forecast.Arima() to forecast future revenue numbers based on the order data we already have in the testing dates*

**How can I apply the models in "train_arimas" to their respective segment in "test_list", using the future values of [,'orders'] (e.g. from "test_list") as the xreg argument in "forecast.Arima()" ?**

My attempt definitely is not using "apply" correctly:

```
forecastFunc <- function(x){
    forecast.Arima(x, h=11, xreg=test_list$x$orders)
}

lapply(train_arimas, forecastFunc)
```

---

*Note*: This is a bit like an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792367/r-arima-forecast-with-xreg-on-large-datasets) I asked, but hopefully the wording is more clear...

*I know that seems kind of strange, methodologically. But in the real application, I've got a set of guaranteed orders by future date, so the "xreg" variable itself doesn't have to be forecast

Comment: Do you want to generate a one-step-ahead forecast for every single element (day) of your `test_list`, supplying a new value of `orders` every day, using the models estimated for the `train_list`? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes yes that's right

Comment: In order to cross check? I always did it with loops

Comment: Yes.. How did you do it with loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
# Split the data according to the variable `segment`
data_s <- split(data, data$segment)

# Estimate a model for each list element for the period [01-05.2014; 20-05.2014]
mod <- lapply(data_s, function(x) auto.arima(x$revenue[1:20], xreg = x$orders[1:20]))

# Apply respective models to the data supplying the regressor `orders`:
res <- mapply(function(mod, data_s) forecast.Arima(mod, xreg = data_s$orders[21:31]), mod, data_s)

# In order to get the respective forecasts (`means`):
forecasts <- lapply(apply(res, 2, list), function(x) x[[1]]$mean)
```

And in order to plot the forecasts on top of the realizations:

```
plot(data_s$Low$revenue, type="l")
lines(21:31, forecasts$Low, col = "red")

plot(data_s$High$revenue, type="l")
lines(21:31, forecasts$High, col = "red")

plot(data_s$Med$revenue, type="l")
lines(21:31, forecasts$Med, col = "red")
```